# Span<T> does not require local variable assignment. Is that a feature?

Tags: c#, c#-7.2, system.memory

I notice that the following will compile and execute even though the local variables are not initialized. Is this a feature of Span?

```
void Uninitialized()
{
  Span<char> s1;
  var l1 = s1.Length;

  Span<char> s2;
  UninitializedOut(out s2);
  var l2 = s2.Length;
}

void UninitializedOut(out Span<char> s)
{}
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, but, as far as I know, `out` is not enforced by CLR anyway.

Comment: `Span` is not special; your own `struct Foo { public int Length => 0; }` will trigger this bug (or "suboptimal handling") as well.

Comment: @JeroenMostert that one *isn't* a bug, though; `Foo` *genuinely has no fields*, so in terms of definite assignment: it is fine

Comment: @MarcGravell: yes -- and no. It's a bad thing: adding a private field would break unsuspecting code, and that sort of brittleness that the client has no control over is undesirable. Allowing this is looking at things with compiler-colored glasses. It *ought* to complain and force `new  Foo()` (still compiling to the same thing, of course), even though you can explain why it won't, by the rules.

Comment: @JeroenMostert adding a public or private field to a struct would do that *today*; adding fields to structs is *not* a safe change. Consider: `Position pos; pos.X = 12; pos.Y = 42; Draw(pos);` . This is a *perfectly legal* way of initializing a mutable struct with public fields (I'll ignore for now the question of whether mutable structs with public fields are *themselves* good ideas...). Now add a `Z` and your existing code stops compiling.

Comment: @MarcGravell: granted. My only remaining quibble then is the compiler diagnostic: "use of unassigned local variable 'structInstance'", which doesn't tell you the real issue is that not all fields have been assigned, and invites you to slap a `new Struct()` to your declaration (just as you'd do with classes), when that's not necessarily the right thing to do. That's orthogonal to allowing this syntax, though -- fieldless structs are degenerate, but not worth issuing a custom warning for.

Comment: @JeroenMostert what's really breaking my noodle: I checked the reference assembly being used here in `ildasm`, and... *it has a field* (OK, it is a dummy field - but: still a field - `.field private initonly object _dummy`)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This looks like an issue caused by reference assemblies, required because of the way that `Span<T>` has framework-specific internals.

This means that in the *reference assembly*: *there are no fields* (edit: this isn't quite true - see footnote).

A `struct` is considered assigned (for the purposes of "definite assignment") if all fields are assigned, and in this case the compiler is seeing "all zero of zero fields have been assigned: all good - this variable is assigned". But the compiler doesn't seem to know about the *actual* fields, so it is being misled into allowing something that is not technically valid.

You definitely shouldn't rely on this behaving nicely! Although in most cases `.locals init` should mean you don't actually get anything *too* horrible. However, there *is* currently some work in progress to allow people to *suppress* `.locals init` in some cases - I dread to think what could happen in *that* scenario here - especially since `Span<T>` works much like a `ref T` - that could get **very very** dangerous if the field *really isn't* initialized to zero.

Interestingly, it *might already be fixed*: see [this example on sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxASwDYB8ACAGAAhwEYBuAWACgcBmIgJgIGECBvKgzounAFgICyACgCUbAgF8OXaZz4EAqgDs0KmGggY0ALzgATUbLZHOAZQAOEJQB4AxgAsICAHwEoZEwQD0X9wQC8BHpwAGYQAK4YMKTeXgThSrYA9mBgcEowBDBJBABEIWgAHrmeAG5OBBjEAW7EAHQAMukA5jD2FJSeFlZ2ji5u9B1cXMqqaOqaOvoA8uEwQklzAyJDwwTlCJWMgVD0jS1tq5xSnZTD8qNqGlq6erPzi5ndNg5OrlAiRuxna5w+UDVgmFItFYvFEik0hksjl8kUSj9jlQJEA===). Alternatively, maybe sharplab is using a concrete target framework, rather than reference assemblies.

---

Edit: very oddly, if I load the reference assembly into `ildasm` or reflector, I can see:

```
.field private initonly object _dummy
```

which is the spoofed field in the reference assembly that is *meant* to stop this from happening, but... it looks like it isn't working very reliably right now!

---

Update: apparently the difference here is a [subtle but known compiler issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/25886/files) that remains for compatibility reasons; definite assignment of structs *considers* private fields of types that are known locally, but *does not consider* private **reference-type** fields of types in external assemblies.

Comment: It's even more subtle than that: it does not consider private fields *of reference types* that are in a different assembly, but does consider private fields of value types!

Answer (score 16):

Marc has a great answer. I wanted to elaborate a bit on the history / context.

First of all this is definitely a [compiler bug](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/25886/files). By rules of definite assignment this local is not definitely assigned and any usage should be an error. Unfortunately this bug is hard to fix for number of reasons:

- This bug is old and goes back to at least C# 4.0. That gives customers 7+ years to inadvertently take a dependency on it
- There are a number of structs in the BCL which have this basic structure. For example [CancellationToken](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/CancellationToken.cs,36b17ded8b1a228c).

Those taken together mean fixing this would likely break a large amount of existing code. Despite this the C# team attempted to fix the bug in C# 6.0 when the bug was much younger. But an attempt at compiling the Visual Studio source with this fix showed that the fears around customers taking a dependency on this bug were well founded: there were a number of build breaks. Enough to convince us it would have a negative impact on a significant amount of code. Hence the fix was undone.

The second problem here is this bug wasn't known to all the compiler team members (before today at least). Been ~3 years since the fix was undone and had a bit of turn over since then. The team members who verified how we were generating reference assemblies for `Span<T>` weren't aware of this bug and recommended the current design based on the language spec. I'm one of those developers :(

Still discussing this but most likely we're going to update the reference assembly strategy for `Span<T>`, and other types, so that it avoids this compiler bug.

Thanks for reporting this. Sorry about the confusion caused :(

Comment: That's great context, thanks. I understand the complexities of changing compiler behaviour *even to fix a known bug*, but ... on this occasion it feels that an argument could be made for *at least* making it a compiler *warning*. I know that even that (adding a warning) has problems, and you've probably had that same discussion internally about 8 times. Fascinating issue, though!

Comment: Possibly naive question: is there any harm just adding a `private readonly int _evenDummier;` alongside the `private readonly object _dummy;` in the reference assembly, if that would cause the compiler to spot it? although I guess that would cause the exact same hard breaks as changing the compiler to respect ref-type private fields. Maybe in *new* reference assemblies like System.Memory?

Comment: Is this intentional bug also active when using `<Features>strict</Features>`?

Answer (score 2):

More or less this is by design, since it depends heavily if the underlying `struct` holds any fields itself.

This code compiles for example:

```
public struct MySpan<T>
{
    public int Length => 1;
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MySpan<char> s1;
        var l1 = s1.Length;
    }
}
```

But this code doesn't:

```
public struct MySpan<T>
{
    public int Length { get; }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MySpan<char> s1;
        var l1 = s1.Length;
    }
}
```

It seems that in that case, the struct is defaulted, and that is why it doesn't complain about a missing assignment. That it doesn't detect any fields *is* a bug, as explained in Marc's answer.

Comment: I strongly suspect this is an *error* caused by reference assemblies making the fields **invisible**.

Comment: This also doesn't explain why the compiler doesn't complain about the `out` parameter.

Comment: Because it is initialized with a default in both cases @DavidG

Comment: @DavidG see "all zero of zero fields" in my answer for that

Comment: I guess Marc has a clearer point on the cause, where my answer detects the underlying reason.